# Read Every 2 Bytes from Data file and compare in a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, char, byte

I am new to C++. I have an assignment where I have to read a Little Endian Binary data file and in the data file I have to read every 2 Bytes and check for a header value. I have written the following code but I am not getting correct data. Can someone please guide me on how to approach for this problem.

```
std::vector<char> checkValues = { (char)0xCA5E , (char)0xBEAD };
std::ifstream input("abc.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
if (input)
{
    input.seekg(0, ios::end);
    size_t fileSize = input.tellg();
    input.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    /*How to run loop here for every two byte*/
    {
        char * buffer = new char[2];
        input.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(*buffer));
        std::vector<char>::iterator it = std::find(checkValues.begin(), checkValues.end(), buffer);
        if (it != checkValues.end())
            std::cout << "Element Found" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Element Not Found" << std::endl;
        delete[] buffer;
    }
}
```

I have doubts about my approach, I am still learning. Please if you can guide me towards a better solution that would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: The result of e.g. `(char)0xCA5E` will not be what you think. It will be `0x5e` *only*. You loose the high byte. Your vector will only contain the *two* elements `0x5e` and `0xad`. Also be careful when using `char` for small integer values, as `char` can be either signed *or* unsigned depending on compiler and target.

Comment: Furthermore, `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of the variable `buffer` itself, i.e. the size of `char*`. It's not the size of whatever the variable is pointing to.

Comment: `sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(*buffer)` this won't do what you want either.  `buffer` is a pointer (not an array), so it's size will be four or eight bytes, `sizeof(*buffer)` is defined to be 1.

Comment: Much better to use `char buffer[2]`, and then you don't have to delete the memory at the end either.  (Or even better:  `static constexpr Count = 2; char buffer[Count];` and use `Count` as the argument to `read`.

Comment: 0xCA5E is already 2 bytes (since one 8 bits byte is 2 hex digits).

Comment: Lastly, don't do manual memory handling. If you want an array of two elements why not use e.g. `std::array<uint8_t, 2> buffer;`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Snap!

Comment: Isn't this rather a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: do you have a tutorial link which I can follow for above problem or a sample code. I feel I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your approach is not bad. And there is no optimum solution. There are roundabout 42 million solutions :-)

There are some necessary optimizations. They are all shown in the comments under your question.

Ands the while loop can simply be done with testing the filestream variable. The "bool operator !" is overloaded for that variable type. The result will be false in case of error. Also for eof (end of file).

I would like to show you the more "C++" or "Object Oriented" approach. You start thinking what you want to do and then derive the howto from that. Obviously you want to read something like 2 bytes and compare that 2 bytes with some given value. OK, then let us define a new class TwoBytes. We add some functions, so that the 2 bytes can be read from any istream. And since we want to compare later, we add the comparison operator. All very straight forward. And only one possible solution. You can add many more functions . . .

This should later give you the idea about software design or software architecture. When you a bit more experienced, you will maybe notice that this is the fun part.

So, please see the below as just an example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using Byte = char;

// An ultra  simple class
struct TwoBytes {
    // Hold 2 bytes
    std::array<Byte,2> tb;

    // Define comparison operator
    bool operator == (const TwoBytes& other) { return tb == other.tb; }

    // And overlaod extractor operatror >> . With tha we can easily read 2 bytes
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::ifstream& ifs, TwoBytes& b) {
        // In case of odd file size, we set the 2nd value to 0
        b.tb[1] = 0;        
        return ifs >> b.tb[0] >> b.tb[1];
    }
};


int main(void)
{
    const TwoBytes compareValue1 = { '1', '2' };
    const TwoBytes compareValue2 = { 0x34, 0x45 };

    // Open the file
    std::ifstream inputFileBinary("r:\\abc.dat", std::ios::binary);

    // We will read the input data to this value
    TwoBytes twoBytes{};

    // This is the loop to read the values
    while (inputFileBinary) {

        // Read 2 bytes
        inputFileBinary >> twoBytes; 

        // In case of odd file size, inputFileBinary would be false. So you could check with "if (inputFileBinary)"

            // Compare values and show result
            if (twoBytes == compareValue1 || twoBytes == compareValue2) {
                std::cout << "Found value\n";
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Did not find value\n";
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps a little . . .